# Pinescript first-run on live bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like something to happen ONCE (during the lifetime of the script) when the following condition is true - ie, when the script is activated/applied to a chart and activated for the first real-time bar encountered:

```
var firstRun = true
if barstate.isrealtime and firstRun and barstate.isconfirmed
    // do something
    firstRun := false
```

However, the condition is ALWAYS being evaluated as true, particularly across all future bars.  My understanding is that the `var` declaration means the variable's value is persistent.

I considered `varip` but that is for intrabar variable persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Your firstRun value is always true because in your if statement you have `barstate.isrealtime and barstate.is confirmed`

Those conditions can’t be true at the same time, therefore your variable can never be changed to false.

This will give you the result you are looking for.

```
var firstRun = true
if not barstate.isfirst
    firstRun := false

if firstRun == true
    label.new(bar_index, high, 'First Run True', color = color.lime)
```

[image: Desired Resut]

Comment: Thanks, but deleting `barstate.isconfirmed` did not work.  The condition keeps evaluating as true for each new candle.  I want it to evaluate true for the first real-time candle only and thereafter remain false.

Comment: I just edited my answer with some code. Try that it gives your desired outcome

Comment: Almost the right answer - I think you misread my question.  Nevertheless, you helped me to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

With smashapalooza's help, I found the solution:

```
var bool firstRun = true
if barstate.islast and firstRun
    // do something
    firstRun := false
```